# In Java 7 64-bit my program freezes on a loop

Tags: java

This is my simple program:

```
public class Test {
    public static Object obj = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        obj = null;
        System.out.println("Start");
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        myThread.start();
        while(obj == null) {
            //System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("Stop");

    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread 1");
        try {
            sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        System.out.println("Thread 2");
        Test.obj = new Object();
        System.out.println("Thread 3");
    } 
}
```

As you can see, I run MyThread thread and while loop of Test class. The loop checks if obj is null and if it is not, I stop it and print "2". MyThread assigns a value to obj. And now the problem:

Under Java 7 64-bit, in case of empty while loop, it is never stopped. However, if I uncomment System.out.print(""), "Stop" under the loop is printed. But for other statements inside the loop (e.g. int i = 1;) my program freezes. Under Java 32-bit everything works fine for all cases.

Could someone explain me this strange behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, in the case when your program freezes, do the prints  "Thread1", "Thread2" "Thread3" come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not thread-safe. The assignment you make to `Test.obj` in the thread aren't guaranteed to be visible in the main thread without some form of synchronization.

Make that static variable private, and provide **synchronized** static getter/tester/setter methods would be one way of implementing this correctly (as long as all accesses go through these methods). Other alternatives exist.

Comment: +1; btw: it will immediately work if you mark the variable `volatile`...

Comment: `volatile` is just too tricky. I'd avoid suggesting that unless the asker has a very, very clear grasp of synchronization issues.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that that there is also `volatile` keyword in Java.
In case of this particular example - Java caches your `obj`.